# Amount of possible disjoint transpositions in $A_n$ and $S_n$

Tags: group-theory

How can I show that the amount of possible products of disjoint transpositions in $S_n$ is strictly more than two times the amount of possible products of even number of disjoint transpositions in $A_n$ for every $n>3$?

Answer (score 1):

The possible products of *disjoint* transpositions straightly correspond to collection of disjoint couples of $\{1,2,...,n\}$. To form $k$ couples ($k\le n/2$) can be done in
$$ T_{n,k}:= \frac{\overbrace{\binom n2 \binom{n-2}2 \ldots \binom{n-2k+2}2}^k}{k!}$$
ways.
This can also be written as
$$T_{n,k} = \binom n{2k}\cdot\frac{(2k)!}{k!}\cdot \frac1{2^k} = \binom n{2k}\cdot (2k-1)(2k-3)\ldots\cdot3\cdot 1$$
Probably this helps.